# What am I doing wrong with pg_hba.conf?

Tags: postgresql, access-control, pg-hba.conf

I'm trying to make it so that local connections to the database don't require a login. So I added the line `local    all   all    trust` to the pg_hba.conf file, but then when I load pgAdmin and try to connect to the server it just says `FATAL: could not load pg_hba.conf`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the lines from your pg_hba.conf that are not commented out (obfuscate any personally identifiable networks/hosts if you like).

Comment: Also, look in the db log, there could be a line just before that FATAL message giving an indication what the problem is, eg. a bad entry in the file.

Comment: Is pgAdmin running on the same machine as the server? Is the Postgres server running and only pgAdmin complaining?

Answer (score 4):

There is likely an invalid entry in pg_hba.conf file. Reload it and then check the PostgreSQL server log for any pg_hba.conf error:

```
pg_ctl reload -D $PGDATA
```

Comment: $ pg_ctl reload -D $PGDATA
pg_ctl: option requires an argument -- 'D'
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this postgres version under win7 can not handle local connections. I had to work with pg very urgently on my local computer so I did not care too much about security so maybe this is not the best solution for a live environment. But my local PC it was enough.

I removed all other uncommented lines from pg_hba.conf and left in only the following one:

```
host    all             all             ::1/0                 trust
```

After this I could connect via command line.

I do not understand why the manual tells no more about this issue. I am pretty sure many people have problem with this.

Comment: "*postgres version under win7 can not handle local connections*" - that's plain wrong.

Comment: Encountered the same issue with postgres 9.5 in Window2021 R2. Postgres log reported: "CDT LOG:  local connections are not supported by this build"